# How do I delete a branch with the name starting with '-'

Tags: git

In an attempt to create a tracking branch I have managed to create a local branch named '-t'. I cannot delete the branch because the branch name is also a parameter. This is on a windows machine.

```
$ git branch -D -t
fatal: branch name required
```

Escaping doesn't help either

```
$ git branch -D \-t
fatal: branch name required
```

Placing the branch name in quotes does not help either

```
$ git branch -D "-t"
fatal: branch name required
```

Using the git gui to try to delete the branch gives the same error message.

I was thinking of just deleting '-t' from .git/refs/heads - Is that enough? Or is there more to it than that? Or is there a way that can delete it from the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `--` option

```
git branch -D -- -t
```

As you can read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

> a double dash (`--`) is used in bash built-in commands and many other commands to signify the end of command options

Git won't treat `-t` as an option anymore, since it comes after the `--`.

Comment: What about deleting the branch name started with '#' like #388Issue?
Tried above method but getting ```fatal: branch name required```

Comment: have you tried using quotes around the branch name? `git branch -D "#388Issue"`

Comment: Oh cool!
That worked. Thank you!
Can you please tell why this worked and not ```git branch -D #388Issue```?

Comment: For anyone else who lands here, I ended up with a branch called "-merged" and this trick, though it's a nice one to learn, didn't work. I just got an error "error: branch '-merged' not found.". I ended up installing Github Desktop and deleting the branch with that.