# Branch name starting with '-' in git

Tags: git, git-svn, git-branch

I am moving from svn to git using git-svn, and some of my branches names started with '-'. Now with help form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034705/how-do-i-delete-a-branch-with-the-name-starting-with) question and [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) migration documentation I am able to pass parameters starting with '-'. but on creating branch git returns an error stating:

> fatal: '-CLOSED-mybranch' is not a valid branch name.

I am using gitlab. The command that I am running to create branches is:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes | cut -d / -f 3- | grep -v @ | while read branchname; do git branch -- "$branchname" --"refs/remotes/$branchname"; git branch -r -d -- "$branchname"; done
```

[This](https://wincent.com/wiki/Legal_Git_branch_names) articles explains legal branch names and I think my branch name is Legal. Can anyone tell me where the problem could be?

PS: branch name not starting with '-' are successfully imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem you can create a branch which name starts with a dash:

```
$ git branch "-test"
error: unknown switch `e'
```

It apparently thinks that I'm trying to set the `git branch` option `-t`, and then gives an error on the following `e`.

It also doesn't work with this command:

```
$ git checkout -b "-test"
fatal: '-test' is not a valid branch name.
```

In this case it actually really says that `-test` is not a valid branch name. So it's probably best if you change your branch names so that they won't start with a dash.

Comment: but i couldn't find any resource stating this!

Comment: Well, you got one now ;)

Comment: It might be that earlier versions of git allowed branchnames starting with a dash. I've tested these commands on version 1.9.0 and it seems this version doesn't allow it.

Comment: This happened in commit `6348624010888bd2353e5cebdc2b5329490b0f6d` in the git sources, back in September 2010.  `git tag --contains` suggests the first revision prohibiting branch names starting with `-` was 1.7.10.

Comment: @torek is indeed right, you can see the commit here: https://github.com/git/git/commit/6348624010888bd2353e5cebdc2b5329490b0f6d

Answer (score 0):

A short answer to your question is: unfortunately, this is not a legal branch name.

The article you referenced is incorrect (likely, simply because it is outdated). The rules for legal reference and branch names can be found in `man 1 git-check-ref-format`:

> Git imposes the following rules on how references are named:
>
> 1. They can include slash `/` for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but no slash-separated component can begin with a dot `.`  or end with the sequence `.lock`.
> 2. They must contain at least one `/`. This enforces the presence of a category like `heads/`, `tags/` etc. but the actual names are not restricted. If the `--allow-onelevel` option is used, this rule is waived.
> 3. They cannot have two consecutive dots `.`.  anywhere.
> 4. They cannot have ASCII control characters (i.e. bytes whose values are lower than \040, or \177 `DEL`), space, tilde `~`, caret `^`, or colon `:` anywhere.
> 5. They cannot have question-mark `?`, asterisk `*`, or open bracket `[` anywhere. See the `--refspec-pattern` option below for an exception to this rule.
> 6. They cannot begin or end with a slash `/` or contain multiple consecutive slashes (see the `--normalize` option below for an exception to this rule)
> 7. They cannot end with a dot `.`.
> 8. They cannot contain a sequence `@{`.
> 9. They cannot be the single character `@`.
> 10. They cannot contain a `\`.

Note that these are the rules for *references*. There is a more strict set of rules for *branches*, they don’t seem to be listed in the manual, but it mentions that:

> a dash may appear at the beginning of a ref component, but it is explicitly forbidden at the beginning of a branch name

which is exactly your case. In other words `foo/bar/-test` is valid, while `-test` is not.

Finally, you can *sort of* cheat by creating a branch with some other name, then going to `.git/refs/heads` and renaming it in there (with `mv`). You’ll then have this branch, you’ll be able to see it in `git branch` (unlike branches, whose names are illegal for a *reference*), but you still won’t be able to checkout it.