# How to delete a git branch named "-a"

Tags: git, version-control

Accidental I have created a local branch named `-a`. I want to delete that branch. I tried using the `-d` option but it is giving error below:

```
error: branch '\-a' not found.
```

Is there any way to delete that branch ?

When i used `list` command it showed me following list:

[image]

Comment: Which command has you tried?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add some additional info.

Comment: Look at this reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034705/how-do-i-delete-a-branch-with-the-name-starting-with

Comment: @Lix Added the image now.

Comment: @Davide It do not work for branch named -a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a branch with the name starting with '-'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034705/how-do-i-delete-a-branch-with-the-name-starting-with)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, it seems that the branch is not named `-a`, but `–a` (with longer dash than the regular hyphen). Try copy/pasting the branch name from the output of `git branch -a` instead of typing it yourself.

Comment: Or use a graphical interface like `gitk`, where you can avoid typing the exact branch name.

Comment: I don't know how you could create a branch with that name, because I tried to reproduce your trouble and I couldn't create a branch named like yours.

`$ git checkout -b '-a'
fatal: '-a' is not a valid branch name.`

 Can you explain that?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly delete the branch what you want by below way:

In the local repo, delete the file name `–a` in `.git/refs/heads` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have special characters in your name you cannot deleted it with the simple

```
git branch -d ...
```

Git  has a special `--` (doubled dashed) option which tell git that the content after the `--` **should not be** parsed as parameters passed to the command but to use the rest of the input as **value** passed to the command.

Its is widely used on many commands and you should use it here as well to remove your branch which start with a special characters.

So in order to delete your branch you should use:

```
git branch -D -- -a
```

[image]

Comment: @YuvrajPatil: This would be correct if the branch name were actually `-a`, suggesting that commenter mkrieger1 is correct: the branch's name starts with a character that *looks like* `-` but is a different character entirely.